# Parse.com How to know if an array does not contain an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

there is a method for PFQuery

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"class"];
[query whereKey:(NSString *)key containsAllObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array];
```

is there similar method to define if there is NO specified object in array?
like

```
[query whereKey:(NSString *)key doesNotContainAllObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array];
```

If no, how to code this method by myself?

Comment: So you want to run a query where the key does not contain any of the objects you specify?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want.

Comment: Today I solved similar issue by writing function in cloud code.

Comment: would u kindly describe what u did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `whereKey:notContainedIn:` method for it.Please have a look at the documentation of [Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS). Here's the sudo code from the link.

```
// Finds scores from anyone who is neither Jonathan, Dario, nor Shawn
NSArray *names = @[@"Jonathan Walsh",
                   @"Dario Wunsch",
                   @"Shawn Simon"];
[query whereKey:@"playerName" notContainedIn:names];
```

Comment: @TrenboloneA Does this actually work? It's not obvious from the documentation that the key given to `whereKey:` can actually be an array.  `playerName` just looks like a string field...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *wantedObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if (/*do logic to match key or obj*/)
            [wantedObjects addObject:obj];
 }];
```

Now you can turn the above enumeration into a function. You can return [wantedObjects copy], which is an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find objects where an Array key does not contain another object, you can simply use `notEqualTo:` as confirmed by a Parse developer here:

https://www.parse.com/questions/pfquery-not-include-any-object-in-array